# Pyfacebook adding extra permission

Tags: python, facebook, permissions, pyfacebook

How and/or where do i add extra permission like email, etc. in pyfacebook while creating a new user?

*Side question:*
Also, there is a facebook link of the pyfacebook tutorial which appears to be broken. Is there some other link? I did some searching but couldn't find anything.

Comment: PyFacebook is deprecated. Please use the REST api.